# Translate raw elastic search query into NEST query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I wonder, if someone could be so kind and translate the following raw elastic search query into NEST? Thanks!

```
var json = @"
{
    ""from"": 0,
    ""size"": 50,
    ""query"": {
        ""constant_score"": {
          ""filter"": {
        ""bool"": {
          ""must"": [
            {
              ""range"": {
            ""attachment.content_length"": {
              ""gt"": 0,
              ""lte"": 500
            }
              }
            },
            {
              ""term"": {
            ""ext"": {
              ""value"": ""pdf""
            }
              }
            },
            {
              ""term"": {
            ""check"": {
              ""value"": false
            }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
          }
        }
      }
    }
";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var searchResponse = await client.SearchAsync<object>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(50)
    .Query(q => q.ConstantScore(cs => cs
        .Filter(f => f.Bool(b => b.Must(
            m => m.Range(r => r.Field("attachment.content_length").GreaterThan(0).LessThanOrEquals(500)),
            m => m.Term(t => t.Field("ext").Value("pdf")),
            m => m.Term(t => t.Field("check").Value(false))
        ))))));
```

or slightly more strongly typed version

```
var searchResponse = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(50)
    .Query(q => q.ConstantScore(cs => cs
        .Filter(f => f.Bool(b => b.Must(
            m => m.Range(r => r.Field(field => field.Attachment.ContentLength).GreaterThan(0).LessThanOrEquals(500)),
            m => m.Term(t => t.Field(field => field.Ext).Value("pdf")),
            m => m.Term(t => t.Field(field => field.Check).Value(false))
        ))))));

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nest.Attachment Attachment { get; set; }
    public string Ext { get; set; }
    public bool Check { get; set; }
}
```

both producing the following query

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                            "range": {
                                "attachment.content_length": {
                                    "gt": 0.0,
                                    "lte": 500.0
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term": {
                                "ext": {
                                    "value": "pdf"
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term": {
                                "check": {
                                    "value": false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 50
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/search.html) are pretty detailed and shows good practices.